# update all Android device that connect to the same url (REST api)

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, push-notification

I new to web services and I just build a restful web service that work just fine, now I need to update all the android mobile devices that connect to the same url with the changes that 1 of the android mobile device just did(with POST).
can someone give me some direction how to do it?

Comment: For example [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) would allow your REST backend to send push notifications to a specific group of devices that are subscribed to a specific "topic" or belong to a specific "group". I won't write a proper answer about it because it's already [covered quite much on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) and then again I'm not even very familiar with it myself. Another option for sharing data across devices is the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

Comment: thank you for the answer